# Cannot open QGIS form from PostGIS Layer with bigInt datatype for my primary keys?

Tags: qgis, postgis

Using QGIS 2.10.1 Pisa / PostgreSQL 9.4 with PostGIS.

In PostgreSQL I have column oid with datatype is bigINT as primary key. These are 16-digit numbers.

In QGIS I can read the table as a layer and view it. If i use the Identify tool,
it shows all attributes in the Identify Results Window. In this Window I have set the option *auto open form*. Normaly if I now use the Identify tool a form opens and show the attributes as a form.

With this table the form does not open. If I change the datatype of the primary key to int, with a 8-digit number, QGIS shows me the form as expected.

I need to use bigInt datatype for my primary keys and I need to show the forms.

Any   suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by the "form"? Can you add a screenshot to your question?

Comment: What was the primary key before? In QGIS, generally, you can't view a Postgres table that does not have a primary key on it.

Comment: By form i mean this : http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/forms.html?highlight=form

Comment: As a new user please take the [Tour] and perhaps also review this for some suggestions about how to make your question attractive to potential answerers http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 The [edit]ing needed to get your question taken off hold needs to be substantial.